# SNMP service keeps creating handles, finally freezes server

Tags: windows-server-2003, snmp

We encountered problems with one server. It always froze after 9 days, then reboot and again after 9 days: server hangs.

What I found in the events log was an Application Popup 333 Error like 10 times a minute or so.

The description of the 333 event was:

> An I/O operation initiated by the
>   Registry failed unrecoverably. The
>   Registry could not read in, or write
>   out, or flush, one of the files that
>   contain the system's image of the
>   Registry.

I tried at least half a dozen different workarounds, found on different websites, including MSKB and serverfault with no success. 
Somebody recommended adding the "handles count" column to the task managers process view, which I did. 
Result: SNMP keeps creating handles. The Performance Monitor Wizard sayed the service had over 2 Million handles the last time the server crashed.

I now have deactivated the service, but what was the cause?

**edit:** We're fortunately not dependent on the SNMP service, so the problem is solved for us, but what, if we actually needed the service? How would I determine what causes the issue? (just in case someone else has the same problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, high (enough) handle count will definitely crash the server.  If I recall correctly, the SNMP service can load extension DLLs created by other people (ie not Microsoft).  I'd bet one of those extensions simply had a handle leak which is similar to a memory leak.  It happens -- it's software :(

Comment: Is there a way, to find out, which DLLs are currently loaded by the SNMP service?

Comment: Using <a href="http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx">Process Explorer</a> you could find the snmp service exe, and view the DLLs currently loaded in process. Unfortunately the easiest way to figure out which one would be to unload all 3rd-party extensions and test, if it doesn't happen then enable one at a time until it does. AFAIK there is no easy way to tell *which* extension is leaking the handles.

Comment: Gah! Forgot you can't do actual links here in comments, the url is http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx for Process Explorer.

Comment: Since, following the rating of this comment, Process Explorer seems to be way to go, when trying to figure whats the problem, so I mark this as an answer ...